# Vue filtering retuning all Objects in an Array even if they don't match the search criteria

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, filtering

I'm building a glossary in Vue, and adding a computed filter. It's filtering the results, but it's returning all the objects in the array even if they don't match. It seems like it only needs to find one matching object, and then it returns everything. In the JSON example below, there are two entries: B and H, and each have objects within them: BBB, XXX, HHH and XXX. If I type in BBB, I'm returned both BBB and XXX, but I'm not expecting to see XXX.

My JSON data structure looks like this:

```js
[
  {
    "title": "b",
    "link": "b",
    "items": [
      {
        "title": "BBB",
        "content": "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur libero ipsum, euismod posuere posuere ac, rhoncus eget nisi. Praesent ac lorem ut est fringilla porta.</p>",
        "active": false
      },
      {
        "title": "XXX",
        "content": "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur libero ipsum, euismod posuere posuere ac, rhoncus eget nisi. Praesent ac lorem ut est fringilla porta.</p>",
        "active": false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "h",
    "link": "h",
    "items": [
      {
        "title": "HHH",
        "content": "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur libero ipsum, euismod posuere posuere ac, rhoncus eget nisi. Praesent ac lorem ut est fringilla porta.</p>",
        "active": false
      },
      {
        "title": "XXX",
        "content": "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur libero ipsum, euismod posuere posuere ac, rhoncus eget nisi. Praesent ac lorem ut est fringilla porta.</p>",
        "active": false
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Computed filter code:

```js
filteredPosts() {
  let compItems = this.compItems;
  if (this.filterTitle) {
    compItems = compItems.filter(item => {
      return item.items.some(subItem => {
        return (
          subItem.title
            .toLowerCase()
            .indexOf(this.filterTitle.toLowerCase()) !== -1
        );
      });
    });
  }

  return compItems;
}
```

A simplified version of my mark up:

```html
<input
    placeholder="Filter by Name"
    v-model="filterTitle"
/>

<div v-for="(item, index) in filteredPosts" :key="index">
    {{ item.title }}

    <ul v-for="(subItem, index) in item.items" :key="index">
        <li>{{ subItem.title }}</li>
    </ul>

    <hr />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your filter is correctly finding all items that have a matching title in its subitems array, but it doesn't filter out the non-matching subitems. To do that, just add another line to filter the subitems:

```js
filteredPosts() {
  let compItems = this.compItems;
  if (this.filterTitle) {
    // find all items with a matching title in its `items[]`
    compItems = compItems.filter(item => ...);

    // filter out non-matching `items[]`
    compItems = compItems.map(item => {
      const items = item.items.filter(x => x.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.filterTitle.toLowerCase()) !== -1)
      return {
        ...item,
        items // overwrite `items[]` with our filtered one
      }
    })
  }

  return compItems;
}
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      filterTitle: '',
      compItems: []
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.compItems = [
      {
        "title": "b",
        "link": "b",
        "items": [
          {
            "title": "BBB",
            "content": "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur libero ipsum, euismod posuere posuere ac, rhoncus eget nisi. Praesent ac lorem ut est fringilla porta.</p>",
            "active": false
          },
          {
            "title": "XXX",
            "content": "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur libero ipsum, euismod posuere posuere ac, rhoncus eget nisi. Praesent ac lorem ut est fringilla porta.</p>",
            "active": false
          },
          {
            "title": "BBB 2",
            "content": "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur libero ipsum, euismod posuere posuere ac, rhoncus eget nisi. Praesent ac lorem ut est fringilla porta.</p>",
            "active": false
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        "title": "h",
        "link": "h",
        "items": [
          {
            "title": "HHH",
            "content": "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur libero ipsum, euismod posuere posuere ac, rhoncus eget nisi. Praesent ac lorem ut est fringilla porta.</p>",
            "active": false
          },
          {
            "title": "XXX",
            "content": "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur libero ipsum, euismod posuere posuere ac, rhoncus eget nisi. Praesent ac lorem ut est fringilla porta.</p>",
            "active": false
          },
          {
            "title": "BBB 3",
            "content": "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur libero ipsum, euismod posuere posuere ac, rhoncus eget nisi. Praesent ac lorem ut est fringilla porta.</p>",
            "active": false
          },
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  computed: {
    filteredPosts() {
      let compItems = this.compItems;
      if (this.filterTitle) {
        compItems = compItems.filter(item => {
          return item.items.some(subItem => {
            return (
              subItem.title
              .toLowerCase()
              .indexOf(this.filterTitle.toLowerCase()) !== -1
            );
          });
        });
        
        compItems = compItems.map(item => {
          const items = item.items.filter(x => x.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.filterTitle.toLowerCase()) !== -1)
          return {
            ...item,
            items
          }
        })
      }

      return compItems;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.11/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input
         placeholder="Filter by Name"
         v-model="filterTitle"
         />

  <div v-for="(item, index) in filteredPosts" :key="index">
    {{ item.title }}

    <ul v-for="(subItem, index) in item.items" :key="index">
      <li>{{ subItem.title }}</li>
    </ul>

    <hr />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Array method `some` will just return a Boolean (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

You actually want to map and filter where subItem titles include your filterTitle.

```
filteredPosts() {
    if (this.filterTitle) {
      return compItems.map(item => {
        return item.items.filter(subItem => {
          return subItem.title
            .toLowerCase()
            .includes(this.filterTitle.toLowerCase())
        });
      });
    }

    return this.compItems;
  }
```

Comment: Ahhh that explains why mine doesn't work. Ive updated to your version and it seems to be filtering the second level objects as I require (awesome thank you!!) the only thing is the data structure thats returned is a level down (already within items) so im loosing the context of which Glossary letter the object belongs too, any advice for keeping the same JSON structure?

Comment: If you want to setup a jsbin, I'll be happy to help you out.

Comment: Ooo not used that before. I set one up here, the components not re-rendering with the new data on this examples but you can see the data being updated as the filter is being applied - https://jsbin.com/guwitav/edit?html,js,output